# Discord.py - Interaction with multiple buttons

Tags: python, button, discord.py, bots

I've created a command with buttons for my Discord bot.
With the current code below, the interaction with the blue button (button1) works fine. Interaction for the green button (button3) does not work.

How do I create different interactions for different buttons within the same command?

I am using discord.py and discord_components

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        "This is a button test.",
        components=[
            [
                Button( 
                    style=ButtonStyle.blue,
                    custom_id="button1",
                    label="Blue button",
                    emoji="",
                ),
                Button(
                    style=ButtonStyle.red,
                    custom_id="button2",
                    label="Red button",
                    disabled=True,
                    emoji="",
                ),
                Button(
                    style=ButtonStyle.green,
                    custom_id="button3",
                    label="Green button",
                    emoji="",
                ),
            ]
        ]
    )
    blue = await bot.wait_for(
        "button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id == "button1"
    )
    await blue.send(content="Button clicked!", ephemeral=False)
    green = await bot.wait_for(
        "button_click", check = lambda k: k.custom_id == "button3"
    )
    await green.send(content="Button smashed!", ephemeral=False)
```

The bot is currently waiting for the blue button to be pressed. Then the green button works. Obviously I want them to work at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check if the buttons custom id is either `button1` (blue) or `button3` (green)

```py
    button = await bot.wait_for(
        "button_click", check = lambda i: i.custom_id in ["button1", "button3"]
    )

    if button.custom_id == "button1":
        await button.send(content="Button clicked!", ephemeral=False)
    else:
        await button.send(content="Button smashed!", ephemeral=False)
```

If you want the buttons to constantly work, put the code above into a while loop