# Editing specific button in Button class

Tags: discord.py

In discord.py, I've made a class of 5 buttons and I want one of those buttons to change/edit whenever the user interacted with that specific button without having to make any changes to the other 4 buttons.

For example:
If i have 5 buttons one, two, Play, three, four respectively.
On should become Stop when someone interacted with that button

Comment: Could you give more detail/context please? Maybe even a [MRE]?

Comment: Button should change on interaction like for example i have button named On and if someone click it it should become OFF

Comment: Okay... How/why are all five buttons defined as one class? Could you share a (minimal, but still self-contained and and functional) code example of what you're talking about?

Answer (score 2):

### How to disable a button

The [`discord.ui.Button()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20ui%20view#discord.ui.Button.disabled) class has a `disabled` parameter. When set to `True` this disables the button. When the view is edited, the message should be updated.

### How to change the label of a button

The The [`discord.ui.Button()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20ui%20view#discord.ui.Button.label) class has a `label` parameter. It can be set to a string when instanced and changed when pressed.

### Example Code

```py
class disable_buttons(discord.ui.View):  # View object
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        for i in range(5):  # Add five buttons
            self.add_item(self.button_disable(str(i)))

    class button_disable(discord.ui.Button):  # Button class
        def __init__(self, label):
            super().__init__(label=label)  # set label and super init class

        async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
            self.disabled = True  # disable button  
            await interaction.message.edit(view=self.view)  # update message
            await interaction.response.send_message("Worked!")  # respond

@tree.command(name="button_test", description="Test buttons", guild=discord.Object(
    id=insertguildidhere))
async def button_test(interaction):  # command to add buttons to response
    await interaction.response.send_message("Worked!", view=disable_buttons())  
    # disable_buttons is the view class to add to the message
```

*note: if you want to change the `label` parameter you would do the same thing but edit the callback function to change the `self.label`*

### Output

[image: Output image]

### Resources

- [Add button components to a message (discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722188/add-button-components-to-a-message-discord-py)
- [Multiple button interactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72791086/discord-py-interaction-with-multiple-buttons)
- [View class docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20ui%20view#discord.ui.View)
- [Button class docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20ui%20view#discord.ui.Button.disabled)
- [Button label docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20ui%20view#discord.ui.Button.label)